# Does inducing charge on a grounded conductor do work?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, work

Imagine a grounded conductor as an plane of infinite area. If I bring a charge to a close proximity to the plane, it induces some charge distribution on the conductor.

The question is: is any work being done on the (induced) charge during this process?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, By taking an electrical image of the charge wrt plane you can understand that the magnitude of work will be:
$$ |W| = \frac 1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac {q^2}2 \left|\frac1y-\frac1d\right|$$
where we carry a charge q from distance d to distance y from earthed conducting plane.

Comment: No, this is the work done on my charge, not on the charges of the plane.

Comment: there will be work done in changing the configuration of charges of plane as they will become more concentrated even though the potential of plane remains zero.

Answer (score 1):

> is any work being done on the (induced) charge during this process?

Clearly, the *potential* energy of the induced charge is unchanged since the conductor is an equipotential surface.

The induced charge is, I assume, static so the *kinetic* energy of the induced charge is unchanged.

If work has been done on the induced charge, in what form is the energy stored?

Answer (score 1):

Good question! At first I thought work was done, because it seems akin to me how an electrophorus works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophorus

Assume you have brought the charge close to the plane (assume it is positive) and this caused electrons to be drawn to the region of the plane under the charge. Now if you could disconnect a disk of the plane directly under the charge it would have a more negative charge density than the rest of the plane.

However, to get useful work from this charged disk you would have to then  move the positive charge away from the plane again. This is when the work would actually be done, leaving you with a negatively charged disk.

So I think the answer is no, no work is done. However if you disconnected the disk when the positive charge was close (so that the configuration of charges on the plane was trapped so to speak) then moved the positive charge back to its starting point work would be done.